# Java application security assessment

Tags: penetration-test, java

I will be soon asked to "pentest" a Java application. This application is meant to be run on a local machine (not a web based application) and can interact with databases and a few others services when needed.

However, I am not used to pentest application not running on the web or not written in low-level languages such as C. I have browsed the web in order to find more information about some particular aspects of Java pentesting : it seems like many websites recommend using Javasnoop (a tool similar to Burp, but for Java application).

Unfortunately, these articles and sources were quite old, so I'm not sure that Javasnoop is still a reliable tool to pentest an application running under Java 8. What are your thoughts about it ?

I would really appreciate if someone could lead me on a few procedures or courses about Java pentesting, I am not very satisfied of what I could find on the internet by myself for the moment.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: you might want to look at https://github.com/cphr/javafuzz

Comment: I have tested some desktop applications, I have found SQL Injection and issues about access controls; my process is decompiling Java application (file JAR) and analyzing the source code, in this way, I can undesrtand very well the applications and its functions and finally I test it to detect vulnerabilities.

Comment: @ColinPickard : Thanks for the link. But don't you think that a 2007 tool might be obsolete right now ?

Comment: @hmrojas.p The application I have to test is really huge and I am alone to perform this task. Reading the whole code is a correct solution ?

Comment: maybe you could identify main points in the source code and don't analyze the complete source code or if you can and you have the possibility, you could run a code analyzer tool